# How do I make a JavaScript bookmarklet that opens a specifically sized new window?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm trying to make a bookmarklet that opens a new editable Chrome tab that's a notepad, but I want it to open in a separate *window,* not tab, and I want it to be pretty small. The current code I have is as simple as `javascript:window.open('data:text/html, <html contenteditable>', 'width=500, height=500')`, but it doesn't open in a new window, nor does it scale it to be 500x500 pixels. How do I make it so it executes and makes a window about this size? [Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haOK8.png)

Comment: I got it to work by adding the [second parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) for the `.open()` function; the `windowName`. So changing the code to `window.open('data:text/html, <html contenteditable>', "myPopup", 'width=500, height=500')`. Be aware of any Ad Blockers attempting to snipe the pop up though, it might be opening and getting instantly killed by an aggressive Ad Blocker.

Comment: @AlainDoe So the bookmarklet opens the window fine and everything, correctly sized, however the window that pops up isn't actually editable; it's just an about:blank page with no attributes. The <html contenteditable> attribute doesn't actually work for some reason, whereas previously it did. I can't seem to figure out how to solve this issue :/